# why the class for h4 tag don't work probably

Tags: css, css-transforms

my problem is i desing a div in parallelogram style 
i open a h4 in that div and using a class for that 
but the won't work 
my question is why ?

```css
.parall {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 35%;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

.title {
  transform: skewX(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parall">
  <h4 class="title">title</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lf2r4c15/

Comment: relook to my updated code

Comment: you need skew(45deg) not skew(0deg)

Comment: @TemaniAfif tnx bro ... i think if i set that to zero it back to normal sitaution

Comment: It works fine as it is: https://jsfiddle.net/ndurjat5/